# How do I resolve " error L2029: 'KMTGCD' : unresolved external"?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, masm

I have created an assembly program that takes two numbers from the user and finds the greatest common divisor. However when I try to run the program I get the error - Error L2029 : 'KMTGCD': unresolved external. Below are the two files I have created and am trying to use. I am using Dos-box to run/compile the program.

Main file

```
;;File Name: Assignment7.asm
                include PCMAC.INC
                .model small
                .586
                .stack 100h
                .data
intro           db "This program will take two numbers and find the greatest common divisor. $"
firstNUM        db "Please enter the first number: $"
M               dw ?
secondNUM       db "Please enter the second number: $"
N               dw ?
Greatest        db "The greatest common divisor is: $"
GCD             dw ?
                .code
                extrn GetDec:near
                extrn PutDec:near
                extrn KMTGCD:near

main            proc
                _Begin
                
                _PutStr intro    ;;print what the program does
                _PutCh 13, 10
                _PutStr firstNUM        ;;print the msg to user for what to do
                call GetDec         ;;call the extrn procedure to get a number
                mov M, ax       ;; store that number in N
                
                _PutStr secondNUM   ;;print another msg to the user for the second number
                call GetDec
                mov N, ax           ;; store 2nd number in N
                
                
                mov ax, M           ;; put M in the ax register
                mov bx, N           ;; put N in the bx register
                
                call KMTGCD
                mov GCD, ax         ;;store the ax value from KMTGCD in GCD
                
                mov ax, GCD
                _PutStr Greatest
                call PutDec
                _PutCh 13, 10
                _Exit 0
                
                
main            ENDP
                END main
```

Source Code file

```
;; FIle name:KMTGCD.asm


                include PCMAC.INC
                .model small
                .586
                .data
GCD             dw ?
                .code
                PUBLIC KMTGCD
                
KMTGCD          proc
                push bx
                
                cmp ax, 0           ;;check if ax = 0
                je axisZero         ;; if 0 jump to axisZero
                cmp bx, 0           ;; check if bx = 0
                je bxisZero         ;; if 0 jump to bxisZero
                
                cmp ax, 0
                jl  axislessZero
                cmp bx, 0
                jl  bxislessZero
                
                
loop_1:     
                cmp bx, ax          ;; compare ax and bx
                je  exit_loop           ;; if equal exit
                Jl else_1           ;; if ax is less than bx jump to else_1
                                    ;; if ax is greater than bx continue to then_1      
then_1:
                sub bx, ax          ;; ax - bx = ax
                jmp loop_1
else_1: 
                sub ax, bx          ;; do bx - ax = bx
                jmp loop_1
exit_loop:  
                mov GCD, bx         ;;put value in bx into GCD
                jmp exit
                
axisZero:       
                mov GCD, bx         ;; set GCD equal to the value in bx (N)
                jmp exit
bxisZero:
                mov GCD, ax         ;;set GCD equal to the value in ax (M)
                jmp exit

axislessZero:
                cmp ax, -32768
                je then_2
                neg ax
                jmp loop_1
bxislessZero:
                cmp bx, -32768
                je then_3
                neg bx
                jmp loop_1

then_2:
                cmp ax, bx
                je bothMIN
                mov ax, 16384
                jmp loop_1
then_3:
                cmp bx, ax
                je bothMIN
                mov bx, 16384
                jmp loop_1
bothMIN:
                mov GCD, -32768
                jmp exit
exit:
                mov ax, GCD         ;;returned value in ax
                pop bx              ;;restore bx
                ret
KMTGCD          ENDP
                END
```

I was expecting the program to run but it just gets a compilation error. I have tried to look at other examples that people have posted with the same error code but can't find a solution to my issue.

The commands I am using to run everything are the following (assignment 7 is the name of my main file)

```
masm assignment7
link assignment7,,,util;
assignment7
```

Comment: Yes, in dosbox the commands I am running are the following -                                 "masm assignment7"   followed by 
"link assignment7,,,util;" and then I am trying to run the program by simplying typing "assignment7"

Comment: I have added this into my description

Comment: You have two files. You need to assemble both into object files and then link both together. I can' tell which source code file name assignment7.asm is since you dont mention the file names above the code you have provided.

Comment: I fixed that now too. I have also ran the masm KMTGCD, link KMTGCD,,,util, for KMTGCD.asm as well

Comment: You'd have to assemble each file separately and then link. So something like `masm KMTGCD` and `masm assignment7` then if I recall the syntax correctly for the command line the link stage would be `link assignment7.obj KMTGCD.obj,,,util,`

Comment: gotcha, I just found that too and it runs now. However, I am getting stuck in a loop and it seems stuck in my KMTGCD.asm file and it is never exiting back to my assignment7.asm. just keeps constantly asking for new numbers and never prints what the greatest divisor is.

Comment: That is a totally separate problem now. You are now able to at least run the program. I'd recommend stepping through with a debugger. You can download Turbo debugger online (TD.EXE)

Comment: Turbo Debugger comes with Turbo Assembler (but it will debug programs assembled with MASM/LINk.EXE too). I believe the TASM 2.x here can be installed and the TD.EXE (turbo debugger) will run in dosbox. https://winworldpc.com/product/turbo-assembler/20